# c++ static, dynamic libraries - analyzing UE4 build system

Tags: c++, linker, unreal-engine4

**TL:DR;** Static/Dynamic library and data sharing in UE4.

So all libraries are static or dynamic but no "mixed" solution?

**Long description:**

I'm browsing the UE4 source code and found that they are using a modular system. So they're building libraries (static or dynamic, based on the IS_MONOLITHIC define) and they are linked based on the build configuration files (like Core.Build.cs).

Let's read the "OpenGLDrv" module's Build file. It depends on the Core and Engine (and so on) libraries, so I guess they are linked to the OpenGLDrv library.

And checking the Launch module, in the Build file they set up dynamic module dependencies for the D3DXX and the OpenGLDrv libraries.

And here comes my problems:

- If they are dynamically loaded modules, they have to be dynamic libraries (dll in Windows). If it's not true, are they linked statically?
- If linked statically, how are they handling the global/static data sharing? Both the Launch and OpenGLDrv depends on the Core module which is linked statically to both libraries.
- If the OpenGLDrv is a dynamic library and the Launch and Core are not, the data sharing problem still exists.

**More specifically**

I've tried to implement a similar system. I'm using visual studio and my current target platform is Windows only (but I'm writing the code in a platform-independent way).

Currently I have 5 following modules:

- **Core**: It has the really core things like math classes, logger, misc, and the module manager.
- **Modules**: The base classes for the "implementable" modules: InputDevice, GraphicsDevice and so on. The Core is linked to this.
- **OGLDevice**: This supposed to be a dynamic library. It implements the OpenGL-specific GraphicsDevice. Both the Core and Modules are linked to it.
- **Engine**: This is the "main library" which. Both the Core and Modules are linked to this library. It should load the OGLDevice dynamically.
- **Application**: The main executable. The Engine is linked to this.

Here is a pretty cool image drawn by myself in Paint:
[The best design-image ever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty2Jj.png)

If all the 4 libraries are static, there aren't any problem with the dependencies. However, this way the OGLDevice is not a dynamically loaded library, because it is linked to the Engine. Maybe the device itself is not instantiated but still linked to the project.

If the Core, Modules and Engine libraries are static but the OGLDevice is dynamic, data sharing problems comes up. First, the Core is "loaded" by the Engine (because it's statically linked to it) but when the Engine loads the OGLDevice library, it will also "load" its own Core. So every static and global are duplicated.

If all modules would be dynamic, I guess it should work. Is there any way to mix the static and dynamic library thing?

Or how is the UE4 doing this?

Comment: This statement is not true: "Both the Launch and OpenGLDrv depends on the Core module which is linked statically to both libraries".  You can't link to libraries and also when linking statically only one instance of a library is included in the final executable no matter how many times is it linked in.

Comment: I was inaccurate: when static library A depends on static library B and "they are linked" (I know, they are actually not), the missing symbols in A are looked up from other dependant libraries available at link-time (so from B as well).

But I think this is the main reason why it works when using static libraries only. Because the dynamic library is handled as a separate process/executable/whatever, a different version of the static libraries (more specifically the obj files) are exist in it.